# Why is Helium ground state a singlet?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics, symmetry

I see that in the 1$s$ orbital the electrons have to have different spins, still there is two possible states,

- a singlet state with an anti-symmetric superposition of spins and symmetric spatial part
- a triplet state with symmetric superposition of spins and anti-symmetric spatial part

So, the question reduces to WHY the first one? I have read somewhere else that a ground state has to have a symmetric spatial wave function always but without further reasoning why this should be necessarily true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think of the spatial part alone. The unique combined state where both are in the 1s state is symmetric.

For the total state to be antisymmetric we must have that the spin part is antisymmetric (because the full state space is the tensor product of the spatial and the spin part). This is the lowest possible energy state.

Comment: Yes, I have understood this part of the deal. WHY should the spatial part be symmetric though???

Comment: There is no a priori reason why the spatial part should be symmetric. However, if for each electron individually there is a unique ground state, there is just one possibility for both to be in that ground state. That state just happens to be symmetric.

Comment: If the individual ground state would be degenerate, then it should be possible to have a spatially antisymmetric ground state. Note that the interaction term in the Hamiltonian could a priori also change things (in fact it doesn't change what is the ground state, but it does influence its energy eigenvalue)

Comment: Well if there is no a priori reason for the ground state to have a symmetric spatial wave function than how can we know its the symmetric one? Is this something we know from spectroscopy where we see that $\Delta s = 0$ selection rule should only yield transitions from singulets?

Comment: The ground state is the state of lowest energy. An exact computation is not easy, but not strictly necessary either. The electrostatic Hamiltonian can be treated as a perturbation of the sum of two Hamiltonians for a Helium ion with a single electron, where the perturbation corresponds to the interaction between the electrons. The Helium ion states can be computed exactly, and as you know the lowest energy state is called 1s. The state space of two electrons is the tensor square of that of one, and a basis of eigenfunctions is a perturbation of the tensor product basis.

Comment: The energy eigenvalues can be obtained e.g. by perturbation theory as the sum of the energies of the ionic states plus a correction due to the interaction term.

Comment: The $1s\otimes 1s$ state (symmetric) corresponds to an energy of -108.8 eV plus a correction of almost 30 eV. The $1s\otimes 2s \pm 2s\otimes 1s$ (either symmetric or antisymmetric) states have an energy of -68 eV + a correction term if I'm calculating correctly. Intuitively it seems clear that the interaction term can only raise the energy. If you want to know for sure, you can approximate it e.g. through perturbation theory (I'll leave that to you).

Comment: Ok, I was rather looking for some evident reasoning other than computing it by pertubation theory. I was just asking myself wether I was missing something obvious here.

Comment: The evident reasoning would be to remark that 1) the single electron ground state is non-degenerate, 2) the 2 electron ground state has to be the one in which both are in the single electron ground state 3) this state is symmetric

Comment: What is not evident is the relative smallness of the interaction term. If you assume it, you're done, otherwise i don't think you can avoid some computations