# Why must the ground state of helium be a singlet?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, quantum-spin, fermions, ground-state

Every reference I have seen, including e.g. question (a) on page 5 of [these notes](http://www.physics.udel.edu/~msafrono/626/Lecture%204.pdf) or the comments in the answer of [this post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/312312/why-is-helium-ground-state-a-singlet), use a hand-wavy perturbation theory argument for non-degeneracy of the ground state to explain why the ground state of helium is a singlet.

> However, is there any **mathematically rigorous** way to prove that this is actually the case?  (Ideally without perturbation theory, but using precise perturbation bounds would also be accepted begrudgingly).

Any help is much appreciated! :)

Comment: It's highly doubtful that there exists a ""rigorous"" derivation that's any more illustrative than the standard one, that you dismiss as hand-wavy. At best, it would be just the same argument at heart, but spelled out in pages and pages of grungy inequalities...

Comment: @knzhou Even those inequalities would be better than nothing--at least they would be rigorous!  But I haven't seen anyone actually prove that the magnitude of perturbations of all orders is sufficiently small to justify that we can still use the symmetry / antisymmetry spatial and spin components from the unperturbed approximation.

Comment: See, for example, Chapter 6 in Mark Fox, A Student's Guide to Atomic Physics, Cambridge University Press.